# How can I retrieve the return value of a method of a class within the same class?

Tags: python, django, class, methods, django-class-based-views

I was wondering if I could get any insight on this.

So far, I have this class:

```
class MaterialTaggingListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        vLatestUpdateDate = ScTaggingLargeTableIp.objects.values('update_date').order_by('-update_date')[:1]
        request = self.request
        if 'selectedcountries' not in request.session:
            vSelectedCountries = ['CN']
        else:
            vSelectedCountries = request.session['selectedcountries'] 
            vSelectedPlants =request.session['selectedplants'] 
            vSelectedValClass = request.session['selectedvalclass'] 
            vSelectedCoCode = request.session['selectedcocode'] 
           columns = request.session['selectedtags']            
        return ScTaggingLargeTableIp.objects.filter(update_date = vLatestUpdateDate,plant_country__in=(vSelectedCountries), plant__in=(vSelectedPlants), valclass__in=(vSelectedValClass), company_code__in=(vSelectedCoCode))

    def set_columns(self): 
       request = self.request
       columns = request.session['selectedtags']
       return columns

    columns = set_columns()
```

With this code above, I got the error: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible and how I could resolve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you need to initialize class attributes in `__init__` method for this to work, because you cannot set the attribute to the object that has not been created yet.

But since you are using `self.request` object in the `set_columns` method, you need to override the `setup` method in which `request` object is initialized:

```
class MaterialTaggingListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.columns = self.set_columns()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. You need to create an instance of a class to call non-class methods on it. What you can do - is either not set `columns` as a class-level variable, or make `set_columns` a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), but in that case it won't be able to receive request in it (Django will create an instance of your view before processing request).

If you want to persist `columns` value between requests - store it in database or in cache.